# Info.plist is always readonly

Tags: finder, macos, permission

I want to edit Finder Info.plist file that is located here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

But when I try to edit the file by `vi` the file is readonly.

```
# vi /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

When I try to `chmod` or `chown` the file nothing happens.

When I try to change file permission from Finder I get the error: "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."

The Locked checkbox in Get Info is disabled.

I also tried:

```
sudo chflags nouchg Info.plist
```

But after all that, file is still readonly.

What is preventing `root` from editing this file on OS X El Capitan 10.11.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That file is explicitly protected by SIP.

```
ls -lO /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

The "restricted" flag listed by the O (capital letter o) option to the `ls` command shows SIP status of the file.

To change that one file, you would need to disable System Integrity Protection. SIP is a security measure to prevent any User up to and including root (and thereby most malware) from modifying system files.

To disable:

- Boot into Recovery Mode (Hold Command+R while turning on Mac).
- Open Terminal (Click Utilities > Terminal).
- Type: `csrutil disable`
- Restart your computer, and SIP will be disabled.

You should now be able to modify Finder's info.plist file.

Comment: thanks it worked but i booted into recovery by holding Command+R

Comment: @Seifolahi, Yes, per [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) it's "command ⌘ + R", and the answer has been edited to reflect that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help: I have both csrutil disabled and it still is inaccessible: https://i.imgur.com/ITrcH1b.png